# Private Docker registry deleting fails

Tags: java, docker

I am running a private docker registry (registry:latest!) I also added "storage.delete.enabled: true" inside my configuration file and so I am trying to delete a given image by a tag using java.

```
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add the Jackson Message converter
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    // Note: here we are making this converter to process any kind of response,
    // not only application/*json, which is the default behaviour
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
    messageConverters.add(converter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
        request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    });

    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = restTemplate.headForHeaders("http://localhost:5000/v2/sample/manifests/java8");
    final String digest = httpHeaders.get("Docker-Content-Digest").get(0);
    System.out.println(digest);

    restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:5000/v2/sample/manifests/" + digest);
```

And the given error will be thrown:

```
sha256:fde4d1ff844409053961d99a3fd955ad21599a7449e7ad58c805b4fa87b6307b

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"manifest unknown"}]}
]
```

The digest whenever I push the image:

```
$ docker push localhost:5000/demo-group/sample:java8
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/demo-group/sample]
35c20f26d188: Layer already exists 
c3fe59dd9556: Layer already exists 
6ed1a81ba5b6: Layer already exists 
a3483ce177ce: Layer already exists 
ce6c8756685b: Layer already exists 
30339f20ced0: Layer already exists 
0eb22bfb707d: Layer already exists 
a2ae92ffcd29: Layer already exists 
java8: digest: sha256:f841a2abd0422364ec94bb633a56707a38c330179f2bbccebd95f9aff4a36808 size: 2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still used the wrong header. As described on the page, the header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
" is required.

See: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#deleting-an-image